# React useState - file Reader is not updated

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use the following code in order to get the values from an file upload (which is XML). But the console output is always undefined.

Would someone point me to my mistakes?

My JS code:

```
export default function XYZ() {
     ...
     const [xmlUpload, setXmlUpload] = useState(null);

    function uploadXMLHandler(e) {
        setXmlUpload(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (xmlUpload != null) {
            var convert = require('xml-js');
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var result =  fileReader.readAsText(xmlUpload);   
            console.log(result);
        }
    });


...
```

my HTML Code is

```
  <div className="uploadXML">
            <input type="file" onChange={uploadXMLHandler} />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the FileReader wrong. `FileReader#readAsText` does not immediately return the result, it starts reading asynchronously. It will fire the `load` event when it's done. So you should be listening to that event, like so:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = () => console.log(fileReader.result);
var result =  fileReader.readAsText(xmlUpload);
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problems. :)